Does Anyone know what Lego set these are from?
I have Lego bags that say 151R1 on them I would like to try to get the book to do these legos. It says it’s from 2017. There is another number on the bag 135149. Any idea how I could figure out which Lego set?

Please post a clear picture or two. Numbers are irrelevant for LEGO sets and usually only used for internal needs.
